The formula fields should be available /visible only on record page and not record edit page how to solve this?
The formula fields should be available /visible only on record page and not record edit page how to solve this ?

Have you checked this? - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387081&type=1

Is there any chance to delete formula fields in record edit page in lightning interaface?

The simplest way to do this is to create a validation rule on the object that prevents users from editing the field.
Example:
ISCHANGED(Formula_Field__c)

If you don't want it to be visible at all you can set up dynamic forms, this is the better option as it will help you with future issues:
Once set up, ensure Dynamic Forms is enabled for your object.
Edit Field Visibility:
Open the Lightning Record Page in Lightning App Builder.
Select the field section where your formula fields are located.
Use the visibility settings to configure the formula fields to be visible only when the record is not in edit mode.
